# Solving "Nesting Depth" from code jam 2020?

Tags: python

## CODE OF WAR - 2020: NESTING DEPTH

### This is the question:

you can also go to https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/000000000019fd27/0000000000209a9f for the question

```
tl;dr: Given a string of digits S, insert a minimum number of opening and closing parentheses into it such that the resulting string is balanced and each digit d is inside exactly d pairs of matching parentheses.

Let the nesting of two parentheses within a string be the substring that occurs strictly between them. An opening parenthesis and a closing parenthesis that is further to its right are said to match if their nesting is empty, or if every parenthesis in their nesting matches with another parenthesis in their nesting. The nesting depth of a position p is the number of pairs of matching parentheses m such that p is included in the nesting of m.

For example, in the following strings, all digits match their nesting depth: 0((2)1), (((3))1(2)), ((((4)))), ((2))((2))(1). The first three strings have minimum length among those that have the same digits in the same order, but the last one does not since ((22)1) also has the digits 221 and is shorter.

Given a string of digits S, find another string S', comprised of parentheses and digits, such that:
all parentheses in S' match some other parenthesis,
removing any and all parentheses from S' results in S,
each digit in S' is equal to its nesting depth, and
S' is of minimum length.

Input
The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T lines follow. Each line represents a test case and contains only the string S.

Output
For each test case, output one line containing Case #x: y, where x is the test case number (starting from 1) and y is the string S' defined above.

Limits
Time limit: 20 seconds per test set.
Memory limit: 1GB.
1 ≤ T ≤ 100.
1 ≤ length of S ≤ 100.

Test set 1 (Visible Verdict)
Each character in S is either 0 or 1.

Test set 2 (Visible Verdict)
Each character in S is a decimal digit between 0 and 9, inclusive.

Sample

Input
    
Output
 
4
0000
101
111000
1

  
Case #1: 0000
Case #2: (1)0(1)
Case #3: (111)000
Case #4: (1)

  
The strings ()0000(), (1)0(((()))1) and (1)(11)000 are not valid solutions to Sample Cases #1, #2 and #3, respectively, only because they are not of minimum length. In addition, 1)( and )(1 are not valid solutions to Sample Case #4 because they contain unmatched parentheses and the nesting depth is 0 at the position where there is a 1.

You can create sample inputs that are valid only for Test Set 2 by removing the parentheses from the example strings mentioned in the problem statement.
```

This is my solution:

```
t = int(input())
elem = []
for x in range(t):
    elem.append(list(map(int, list(input()))))
for x in range(t):
    S = ""
    stock = 0
    for y in range(len(elem[x])):
        try:
            if elem[x][y] > elem[x][y + 1] != 0:
                if elem[x][y - 1] != elem[x][y] :
                    if elem[x][y] > elem[x][y - 1] != 0 and y != 0:
                        for z in range(elem[x][y] - elem[x][y - 1]):
                            S += "("
                    else:
                        for z in range(elem[x][y]-stock):
                            S += "("
                S += str(elem[x][y])
                for z in range(elem[x][y]-elem[x][y+1]):
                    S += ")"
                stock = elem[x][y]-(elem[x][y]-elem[x][y+1])
                # print(stock)
            else:
                if elem[x][y - 1] == elem[x][y] and y != 0:
                    S += str(elem[x][y])
                    # print(elem[x][y-1], elem[x][y])
                elif elem[x][y] > elem[x][y - 1] != 0 and y != 0:
                    for z in range(elem[x][y] - elem[x][y - 1]):
                        S += "("
                    S += str(elem[x][y])
                else:
                    for z in range(elem[x][y]-stock):
                        S += "("
                    S += str(elem[x][y])
                try:
                    if elem[x][y + 1] == elem[x][y] and y != len(elem[x]) - 1:
                        continue
                    elif elem[x][y] < elem[x][y + 1] != 0 and y != len(elem[x]):
                        continue
                    else:
                        if y == len(elem[x]) - 1 :
                            stock = 0
                        else:
                            if elem[x][y+1] == 0:
                                stock = 0
                        for z in range(elem[x][y]-stock):
                            S += ")"
                except:
                    if y == len(elem[x]) - 1:
                        stock = 0
                    else:
                        if elem[x][y + 1] == 0:
                            stock = 0
                    for z in range(elem[x][y]-stock):
                        S += ")"
        except:
            if elem[x][y - 1] == elem[x][y] and y != 0:
                S += str(elem[x][y])
                # print(elem[x][y-1], elem[x][y])
            elif elem[x][y] > elem[x][y - 1] != 0 and y != 0:
                for z in range(elem[x][y] - elem[x][y - 1]):
                    S += "("
                S += str(elem[x][y])
            else:
                for z in range(elem[x][y]-stock):
                    S += "("
                S += str(elem[x][y])
            try:
                if elem[x][y + 1] == elem[x][y] and y != len(elem[x]) - 1:
                    continue
                elif elem[x][y] < elem[x][y + 1] != 0 and y != len(elem[x]):
                    continue
                else:
                    if y == len(elem[x]) - 1:
                        stock = 0
                    else:
                        if elem[x][y + 1] == 0:
                            stock = 0
                    for z in range(elem[x][y]-stock):
                        S += ")"
            except:
                if y == len(elem[x]) - 1:
                    stock = 0
                else:
                    if elem[x][y + 1] == 0:
                        stock = 0
                for z in range(elem[x][y]-stock):
                    S += ")"
    print("Case #"+str(x+1)+": "+S)
```

there is a minor error that's causing a Wrong Answer. If someone can take time out go trough my code and please help me out. It's a tedious job. I have been going through my code for 6 hours but could no find the answer.

Comment: That's a lot of code, can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is too tedious to actually go through everything. Notice that its not wrong to collaborate and ask for help but I cant share the code here when competition is running.

In the examples given by GCJ, for 321 --> (((3))1(2)) notice how the number of brackets between 2 numbers is always the difference of the two numbers. the direction of the bracket depends on which number is higher. there are no brackets between two numbers if they are equal. this solution can be done in O(N) where N is the length of the number.

Comment: This code actually works fine for all the examples that are listed in the question and I also tried with random test cases those all worked fine. I would be grateful if you paste this code in your compiler and run the code. There was a small error that was causing and Wrong Answer.